# How to use file and containing folder details to append columns in dataframe

Tags: r, import, tidyverse

I'm fairly new to R so my apologies if this is obvious.

I have a group of data frames which I want to import into R and add details from both the parental folder and file names. I then want to merge them all into a single data frame

Folders and file names are as below:

***Parental folder*** "Quantification" > ***Contains three folders named*** "Ex_1" "Ex_2" "Ex_3" > ***Within each "Ex_" folder are 8 csv files named*** "Pos_1" to "Pos_8"

I want each data frame to have an **"Ex_number"** and **"Pos_number."** column appended, and then to merge the datasets

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your directory to your "Quantification folder", then you can do:

```
list_files <- list.files(recursive = TRUE)
list_files
[1] "Ex_1/Pos_1.csv" "Ex_1/Pos_2.csv" "Ex_2/Pos_1.csv" "Ex_2/Pos_2.csv"

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
merged_data <- set_names(list_files) %>% 
  map_dfr(~read.csv(.x),
          .id = "filename") %>% 
  mutate(Ex_number = substr(filename, 4, 4),
         Pos_number = substr(filename, 10, 10)) %>% 
  select(-filename)
```

This gives you one data.frame.

Comment: Amazing, this is perfect thanks so much! Had to edit the numbers in substr(filename, x, x), but that's not your fault I didn't give you the precise filenames. Keep up the good work!